# Submit jobs to EMR cluster using MRJob

Tags: python, hadoop, emr, mrjob

MRJob waits until each job completes before giving back control to the user. I broke down a large EMR step into smaller ones and would like to submit them all in one shot.

The docs talk about [programmatically submitting tasks](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/runners.html#running-your-job-programmatically), but the sample code also waits for job completion (since they call the runner.run() command which [blocks until the job is complete](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/runners-runner.html#mrjob.runner.MRJobRunner.run)).

Also EMR has a limitation of 256 Active jobs, yet, how do we go about filling up those 256 jobs rather than looping and getting the output on the attached console.

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying, the following is the best I could come up with.

My Initial Attempt, when I realised that a submitted job doesnt get culled when the terminal is detached, was to (in a bash script) submit and kill jobs. However, that didn't work very well because AWS throttles calls to EMR and hence some of the jobs were killed before being submitted.

**Current Best Solution**

```
from jobs import MyMRJob
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format = '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
)
log = logging.getLogger('submitjobs')

def main():
    cluster_id="x-MXMXMX"
    log.info('Cluster: %s', cluster_id)
    for i in range(10):
        n = '%04d' % i
        log.info('Adding job: %s', n)
        mr_job = MyMRJob(args=[
            '-r', 'emr',
            '--conf-path', 'mrjob.conf',
            '--no-output',
            '--output-dir', 's3://mybucket/mrjob/%s' % n,
            '--cluster-id', cluster_id,
            'input/file.%s' % n
    ])
    runner = mr_job.make_runner()
    # the following is the secret sauce, submits the job and returns
    # it is a private method though, so may be changed without notice
    runner._launch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```